# QSound::play("soundpath") call works but a QSound object doesn't

Tags: qt, audio, wav

I am trying to play a sound with **QSound** module.

It try with this code and works:

```
QSound::play(":/sounds/sources/BeepSound.wav");
```

But I want this and doesn't work:

*I create a dynamic instance of `QSound` and played:*

```
sounds = new QSound(":/sounds/sources/BeepSound.wav");
sounds->setLoops(3);
sounds->play();
```

Any tips?

#### Update

I don't want to use others modules like `QMediaPlayer`, `QAudioOutput` because I want something really simple, just play a sound.

Comment: @vizhanyolajos Please refrain from adding spaces inside function-call parentheses, it is not a common style and it makes edits too noisy for those of us in the review queue.

Comment: What OS and Qt Version are you running? QSound is a little weak across platforms and possibly deprecated from what I remember. Have you tried QSoundEffect?

Comment: OS: Windows 8, and Qt 5.4.1

Comment: I'm having this issue too. `QSound` will work in my `main()` function but not in any of my classes. It's very odd.